# How to update specific flutter SDK channel?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

**Currently**, i m using flutter `3.3.9` i want to update it to `3.7.3`

Any particuler **command**?

*Note : I don't want to affect my current code*

Need perment solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these cases, try to use FVM (Flutter Version Management).

```
fvm install 3.7.3
fvm use 3.7.3
```

For get more detail here its official website https://fvm.app/

The advantages is you can any cases you can simply go back to your previous flutter version. And also you can work different flutter project with different version

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I haven't work with it. But seems to be amazing. Will try it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Change channel if you are not in correct channel otherwise go to step 4

1. Open a terminal or command prompt on your computer.
2. Check the available Flutter channels by running the command `flutter channel`.
   This will show you the list of available channels and the current channel you are on.
3. Switch to the desired channel by running the command `flutter channel <channel-name>`.

> For example, to switch to the stable channel, you can run `flutter channel stable`.

4. Choose the version. 
   This is possible now with `flutter version`. In the console do `flutter version` to list the versions available. Then choose a version to switch to: `flutter version v3.7.3`

Comment: i want to update specific channel... not want to switch

Comment: `flutter version` is not supported anymore